# How to insert a random number inside the affiliate tracking code

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Wordpress with **Contact form 7** plugin. Whenever a user submits the form the person will be redirected to a thank you page which is a static page contains affiliate tracking code (javascript). Since the tracking code is always same, I am not able to track the users. I want to know how to change the tracking code in the static thank you page each time when somebody submits the form.

Here is the code (you can see a "tele" which I wanted to be random number each time). We tried to capture variable from URL but what we always get is "tele" in the affiliate tool (Btw. tele is telephone number which user has submitted already. It could be any unique number).

```
<!-- GOAFF TRANSACTION TRACKING -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [],
      hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href
      .slice(window.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1)
      .split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
      hash = hashes[i].split("=");
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  }

  var tele = getUrlVars()["tel-nr"];

  if (tele == null) {
    tele = "error";
  }
  document.write(
    unescape(
      "%3Cscript id=%27pap_x2s6df8d%27 src=%27" +
        ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://") +
        "my.goaff.com/scripts/salejs.php%27 type=%27text/javascript%27%3E%3C/script%3E"
    )
  );

  document.write(
    unescape(
      "%3Cscript id=%27pap_x2s6df8d%27 src=%27" +
        ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://") +
        "my.goaff.com/scripts/trackjs.js%27 type=%27text/javascript%27%3E%3C/script%3E"
    )
  );

  var action = PostAffTracker.createAction("fix_lead"); // do not change
  PostAffTracker.setAccountId("089025de"); // do not change
  action.setOrderID(tele); //  45234 is actual ID number of transaction
  PostAffTracker.register();

  PostAffTracker.setAccountId("089025de"); // do not change
  var sale = PostAffTracker.createSale(); // do not change
  sale.setOrderID(tele); //  45234 is actual ID number of transaction
  PostAffTracker.register();
</script>
```

Comment: I prettified your code. No behavioral changes were made.

Comment: Can’t you just generate a random number? Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

Comment: @ChristianHur, random numbers may coincide.

Comment: Use some service to fetch the users IP, or a custom endpoint, and pass that?

Comment: @kaylined. The real problem is not creating a random number. We are able to fetch users phone number. But inserting this number to the place is the real problem. 

sale.setOrderID(tele); //we have to insert random number her instead of tele

Comment: sale.setOrderID(randomNumber)?

Comment: @Kaylined Yes exactly. I want there a random number each time somebody submits a form.